# Разделение строки на отдельные строки

Tags: python, строки

Здравствуйте! У меня есть e-mail, например example@gmail.com. Как разделить его на имя и доменную часть, чтобы дальше уже работать его отдельными частями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'example@gmail.com'.split('@')
```